# Rails add_index missing when running GENERATE command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Since I am new to Rails, I am following this ['getting started' guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) on rails website.

On section 6.1 Generating a Model, I should run `rails generate model Comment commenter:string body:text post:references` to get a comment model.

Supposedly, this is what should be included in the migration file:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :comments do |t|
       t.string :commenter
       t.text :body
       t.references :post

       t.timestamps
     end

     add_index :comments, :post_id
   end
end
```

But in my migration file, I have everything but this line `add_index :comments, :post_id`.
Instead, I have `index:true` following the `t.references :post`

I can't seem to find an explanation to this, can anyone explain to me what is going on here? Because later on I need to use :post_id, but in my version of migration, it is not clearly declared. I am very confused.

Comment: post your exact migration file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table :comments do |t|
       t.string :commenter
       t.text :body
       t.references :post

       t.timestamps
     end

     add_index :comments, :post_id
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table :comments do |t|
       t.string :commenter
       t.text :body
       t.references :post, index: true

       t.timestamps
     end

  end
end
```

will do same things, both of them will add index to post_id column

also you can later add index to any column any column that you want to add to your model like

```
$ rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts part_number:string:index
```

that will produce this code:

```
class AddPartNumberToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :part_number, :string
    add_index :products, :part_number
  end
end
```

Comment: Good to know, but is that a new feature of using "index:true"?

Answer (score 0):

in above code if you want to create index for post_id then write it as `t.integer :post_id`
else you can try this `add_index :comments, :post`